# Wear OS application: Disable all possible options to closing application on android watch

Tags: android, wear-os

I am working on an alert notification system were user is to be alerted on some events.

In this, I need to invoke the application on the android watch from the controller Android application and keep it until it is required to be closed from the controller application. The user should not be able to close the alert application by any means (e.g. swipe to left, long press etc).

After many tries, we could not find a way to prevent the close by user action.

Minimum wear OS version is 2.0.

Comment: Seems like that would be a denial of service attack that prevents users from accessing their device. I don't think any operating system allows that avenue for abuse (even if it blocks legit use cases).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Build watch face in one with your application. User who install your custom face can't exit with hardware buttons. [Build watch faces](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces)